# Converting multiple functions into one that perform same action in jquery

Tags: jquery, html-lists, nested-lists

I have a simple `html multi-level nested list`, and I am trying to `auto-collapse` all the items, when another one in the list is expanded, currently I made **5** `functions` to do that, *seperate function for each level*. This is what I have done so far:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#tree > li').click(function () {
    $('li').not(this).each(function () {
        $(this).children('ul').hide('fast');
        $(this).children('span').removeClass('explr-minus');
    });
});

$('ul#tree > li > ul > li').click(function () {
    $('ul#tree > li > ul > li').not(this).each(function () {
        $(this).children('ul').hide('fast');
        $(this).children('span').removeClass('explr-minus');
    });
});

$('ul#tree > li > ul > li > ul > li').click(function () {
    $('ul#tree > li > ul > li > ul > li').not(this).each(function () {
        $(this).children('ul').hide('fast');
        $(this).children('span').removeClass('explr-minus');
    });
});

$('ul#tree > li > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li').click(function () {
    $('ul#tree > li > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li').not(this).each(function () {
        $(this).children('ul').hide('fast');
        $(this).children('span').removeClass('explr-minus');
    });
});

$('ul#tree > li > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li').click(function () {
    $('ul#tree > li > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li').not(this).each(function () {
        $(this).children('ul').hide('fast');
        $(this).children('span').removeClass('explr-minus');
    });
  });
});
```

I was wondering if there is any way I can create a single function that works for each level of my nested list?

Comment: Are there any `li`s which are descendants of `#tree` which you do *not* want to run this on?

Comment: I want to run this on each level of `li`s in `#tree`

Comment: try `$('#tree li').click(....` and `$(this).siblings('li').each(....`

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef thanks, it is working.

Comment: totally welcome @JohnDoe .. have a great day :)